# the worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to convert my data to a table to so that the pivot table will update when new data is added, i tried to use a code i found online and updated it with my file but there seem to be some error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wscopy As Worksheet
Dim wspaste As Worksheet
Dim src As Range

   Set wsfilter = Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Filter")

Set src = Range("B5").CurrentRegion
Set ws = wsfilter
wsfilter.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "Filter"

    'update pivot table
    Workbooks("bdncasemacro.xlsm").RefreshAll

   MsgBox ("DONE!")


End Sub
```

i got the error "1004" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcwAI.png)

the error occurs from the debug from the lines

```
wsfilter.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "Filter"
```

Comment: Presumably that should be `Set src = wsfilter.Range("B5").CurrentRegion`. Note: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables.

Comment: how should i edit the code, sorry im new to this

Comment: [Edit] your post.